# Is there a way how to set my Cucumber-js to ignore uncaught errors

Tags: cucumberjs

I am setting up the Cucumber-js (I have migrated Testcafe into Cucumber framework) project which runs well on Chrome and Edge browser. By running on IE 11, the console error causes failing my test scenarios. How to specify in Cucumber-js to ignore uncaught errors? The issue is not reproducible by manual handling or on another browsers as I already mentioned (issue caused by different JQuery version).

Answer (score 0):

I have specified it in 
return runner
               .src('./test.js')
               .screenshots('reports/screenshots/', true)
               .browsers(browser)
               .run({skipJsErrors: true})
               .catch(function(error) {
                   console.error(error);
               });
       })
Which works well for me

Answer (score 0):

CucumberJS has no interaction with a browser. It is selenium or protractor that does that kind of operation so it may be better to ask in those StackOverflow communities. I will say that I have not ever seen a browser console error causing browser controlled tests to fail (unless purposefully implemented that way).

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I did not express myself clearly. The issue which I was hitting was related to JS (observed during test execution). I just added param to skip it inside my run which sorted out the problem.